# redirect to homepage if clicked in google

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've read a several ways to redirect users to homepage, but, what if I need to redirect them just if they got to that page through a search engine like Google or Bing.

I need this because I'm building a cigar webpage and in some countries is demanded to be a certain age to view the content.

Comment: You can't know whether user came from Google. Google uses SSL for their search result pages and HTTP REFERRER information is not being passed when coming from SSL-protected (https://) page to regular page (http://)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cookie or session through PHP/JavaScript on the first website visit, and check on all upcoming visits if the cookie already exists. If not, redirect them to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use the function:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

I believe this will also retrieve the full URL you was referred from.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

---

Ignore the above answer as I read the question wrong.  Best thing to do would be store within a session.  If a session key exists then do not redirect, if it doesn't then do a redirect.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['existingUser'] = true;

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```